# What is different when developing for the iPad versus the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

What are the basic differences between the iPhone and iPad platforms that developers should be aware of?  I am a junior developer at an iPhone development company, and I am still new to this.

And also how does developing for iPhone/iPad differ from other platforms?

Comment: Should this be in community wiki?

Comment: there is no difference, they just hooked on itouch up to a medieval torture rack and stretched it until it was the appropriate size

Comment: @espais, everyone knows that when you get stretched on "the Rack" certain things distort, change, you lose (and gain?) organs, etc. That's what user321210 was asking about.

Answer (score 10):

Full details of the differences between iPad and iPhone can be found in the [iPad Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [iPad Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009446).

iPad programming is basically the same as iPhone programming. The iPad has a larger screen, a few new UI features, and differing performance characteristics.

Comment: See also the new iPad Human Interface Guidelines: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html and the iPhone OS 3.1 to iPhone OS 3.2 API Differences: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/General/iPhone32APIDiffs/